# Are there any function execution time performance profilers that work without source? Only with an .EXE filled with x86 assembly

Tags: debugging, assembly, profiling, reverse-engineering, ida

I am intending to write an extension for IDA Pro or X86 debug - popular low level debuggers (assembly level). This extension would profile how much time CPU spends executing specific functions (similar to a profiler). Then build an execution graph with probabilities (Markov Chain). However I would like to know if something similar already exists before starting.

Visual Studio and other profilers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) do this if YOU HAVE THE SOURCE-CODE. This is for the case without any source code.

Comment: pprof doesn't need source, but without appropriate annotations or a frame pointer, backtraces might not be accurate.

Comment: `llvm-mca` tool does what you need, but it operates on assembly file. You probably can disassemble the binary first and then apply `llvm-mca` analysis.

Comment: `lighthouse` is an IDA plugin that performs code coverage on an executable file. It doesn't consider execution time, just how many times a function (as detected by IDA) is executed. I don't know how you would go from exec time to probability, so this may not be related to your work.

Comment: Thank you. These all answer my question.